# How to inject location directive into Kong

Tags: api, nginx, gateway, api-gateway, kong

I'm trying to inject a nginx location directive into kong but it's not working as expected

In *kong.conf* I have

nginx_proxy_include = /u01/nginx/custom-nginx.conf

In *custom-nginx.conf* I have `location /doc { alias /some/path; }`

Yet it's not being injected into *nginx-kong.conf* which remains untouched:

```
    # .......

    # injected nginx_admin_* directives

    location / {
        default_type application/json;
        content_by_lua_block {
            Kong.admin_content()
        }
        header_filter_by_lua_block {
            Kong.admin_header_filter()
        }
    }

    location /nginx_status {
        internal;
        access_log off;
        stub_status;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        return 200 'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /';
    }
```

Comment: Is it working using an env variable `KONG_NGINX_PROXY_INCLUDE=/u01/nginx/custom-nginx.conf` ?

Comment: @Ôrel your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you!